# How to select element inside label on input radio select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project on Laravel 8. I'm trying to let people change their profile picture from a gallery. That's how I display all the available images

```
@foreach(glob(storage_path('app/public/gallery/*.png')) as $image)
    <div class="col-2 mb-3">
        <label for="{{ basename($image, '.png') }}" class="w-100">
            <img src="{{ url('storage/gallery/' . basename($image)) }}" width="100px" height="100px" />
            <input type="radio" name="profilephoto" value="{{ url('storage/gallery/' . basename($image)) }}" id="{{ basename($image, '.png') }}" />
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**(FREE HTML)**

```html
<label for="photo1" class="w-100">
    <img src="https://example.com/storage/gallery/photo1.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
    <input type="radio" name="profilephoto" value="https://example.com/storage/gallery/photo1.png" id="photo1" />
</label>
<!-- ... more labels&inputs -->
```

And I'm trying to select through jQuery the `<img>` element so I can add some visual effects to it. That's how I'm trying to do it:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="profilephoto"]').on('change', function() {
    $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').find('img').addClass('border')
});
```

But it's not working. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you replace the lavarel code by html code from browser? Also, have you checked browser console for errors?

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: What about trying `$(this).prev('img').addClass('border')`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen not working.

Comment: Works just fine when I run the code, look here https://jsfiddle.net/p791kvbm/

Comment: My bad, its working @CarstenLøvboAndersen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your soulution:

1. Create an onclick function on the radio button and pass `this` like:

```html
onclick="some(this)"
```

2. In that function recieve it in a parameter and get its parent like:

```js
some(eve) {
  parent = $(eve).parent();
}
```

3. then find the image tag in it like:

```js
image = $(parent).find(img);
```

4. Now apply whatever css you want to this element in `image` variable.